# How to prevent injuries when running with peripheral neuropathy?

Tags: running, injury, injury-prevention

I have [peripheral neuropathy](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/peripheral-neuropathy/basics/definition/con-20019948) in my feet and can't feel anything touching my skin. I can feel pressure when it is applied.

What extra safety precautions should I take when starting a running program?

Comment: You will probably need to consult an Athletic Trainer or Physical Therapist. The danger isn't in the running. It is in what you can't feel. You don't want to cause long term irreparable damage to your feet/ankles. My education and gut says, "Sure you can run... but you need to be super smart about it."

Comment: I'm with @Grohlier. Technically, yes, you can run. The danger is that if you do injure yourself you won't feel it and can cause major damage. Talk with your primary care provider.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone's comments above - check with your doctor to see if walking and/or running would be appropriate for your condition.  And working with a physical therapist would help you establish an appropriate exercise program.

Without good sensation, one of the biggest problems you could face is skin problems. Even a simple blister can turn into a big problem if you can't feel the irritation. Also lack of sensation may lead to balance problems, risk of injury and increased risk of falling.  You would certainly need your doctor's clearance before even trying running because depending on the cause or your neuropathy, you could make matters worse.

If your doctor gives you the go ahead here are some things to consider:

- If you haven't already started a good walking program, you may want to start with that to see how you do.  You would need to start gradually, beginning with short walks to see how your feet respond.  Check your skin carefully to look for any irritation.
- Wearing appropriate socks (absorbent, not too tight, soft, cotton) and shoes that fit well with enough padding would be important.  If balance is a problem, walking with [walking poles](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Nordic-Pole-Walking.html) could give you more stability and give you a better workout because they add more trunk and arm muscles to your exercise.
- If walking is a problem, you may want to consider alternative exercises like a stationary cycle, swimming, yoga or tai chi.  Best of luck.